# Property marked as Association is not included in a LINQ Select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, windows-phone-8, entity

i am new in LINQ so i have been following some tutorials and official docs like How to: Map Database Relationships on Developer Network.

I am performing this:

1) Got two classes Locality and Region, there's a one to many relation between this "tables" so than one Region has multiple Localities. I mapped the association like this:

Region:

```
private EntitySet<City> _cities = new EntitySet<City>();

[Association(Storage = "_cities", ThisKey = "RegionId", OtherKey = "RegionId")]
public EntitySet<City> Cities
{
    get { return _cities; }
    set { _cities.Assign(value); }
}
```

The Region has two more fields RegionId and Name. City has two fields too: CityId, Name (beside the RegionId foreign key of course).

Now i populate the database. So i am able to select all cities using a query like the following:

```
var city = from City cities in db.cities
           select cities;
```

And i can see all the properties belonging to City Entity. But when i perform this query:

```
var regiones = from Region region in db.regions
               select region;
```

I only can access to RegionId,Name because the Cities EntitySet is always empty. I dont now what i am doing wrong, so i hope some of you could give me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time guys, i finally found my mistake, i defined the primary key of Region with the flag IsDbGenerated = true, but i am sending a prepared value to the foreign key in City, so the relationship is broken, i fixed the Region Primary Key and Voila.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have LazyLoading enabled on your context. 
If not, you can turn it on or you could use db.regions.Include("Cities") to explicitly load Cities.

Comment: I can´t use db.regions.Include("Cities"), Visual Studio simply says there is not a definition for it.